# why do we need a response object for responding something from a handler in express?

Tags: javascript, function, express

```
const handler = function(req,res){

   //some codes

   res.end();
}
```

why we can't simply return something without a response object in Express module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That helps you to write some async code inside a handler. And when using async code, you won't be able to return from the handler and the only way would be callback or promises. There you can use the res object